# Random LazyInitializationException with @OneToMany

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a legacy database with the following Tables:

```
Police
 id (PK)
 data...

Contract
 id(PK)
 version(PK)
 type


Code
 tab(PK)
 code(PK)
 name
```

I have a jpa Entity Police

```
@Entity
public class Police implements Serializable {


@Id
private long id

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns(value = { @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
private Set<Contract> contracts;

}
```

the Contract entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class Contract implements Serializable {


@Id
private long id;

@Id
private long version;


private String type;



@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "code", referencedColumnName = "type") })
@Where(clause = "tab = 'Type'")
private Set<Code> type;
}
```

Code:

```
@Entity
public class Code implements Serializable {


    @Id
    private String tab;
    @Id
    private String code;

    private String name;
}
```

In the Code table are many different key/values for different applications.
In my case i need the one, where the "tab = 'Type'" and code = type from my Contract.

My Problem is, that if i have more than one Contract for my police, I RANDOMLY? get a org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException.

In my testcase, I do the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int countErrors = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        try {
            readPolice();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            countErrors++;
        }
    }

    System.err.println("errors: " + countErrors);

}

private static void readPolice() throws Exception {
  EntityManagerFactory factory =     EntityManagerFactoryHelper.getFactory(PersistenceUnitsEnum.TEST_STAGE);
  EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
  TypedQuery<Police> namedQuery = em.createNamedQuery(...);
  Police result = namedQuery.getSingleResult();
  Set<Contract> contracts = result.getContract();
  Contract contract = contracts.iterator().next();
  Set<Code> type = contract.getType(); //should be a set with one Entry

  System.out.println(type.size()); //<--- Chance for Exception!!
  em.close();
}
```

I try this whole thing in a loop 15 times.
In about 5-8 tries, i get the LazyInitializationException.
The other times it works.

Any thoughts about this? Why doesn't it fail all the time?

Comment: Can you show your `Code` entity?

Comment: @bigdestroyer: added the Code entity

Comment: I think you might need `IdClass` annotation on `Code` if you want it to have a composite primary key defined this way. Here's an example: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Id_Class

Comment: Doesn't change anything :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I override the equals/hashcode in the Contract entity it works.
Why the problem occured randomly ... I don't get it ...

Answer (score 1):

Just encountered this one. The key word being 'random'. One of my colleagues encountered this exception consistently on her laptop while I never encountered the same. She could reproduce the exception only on IE & Edge.

Finally realized it had to do with Tomcat versions. She was running an older version, while I had a later version - 8.5.8. She upgraded the local Tomcat to this version and the exception is no more encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the code with println is in the transaction.

`LazyInitializationException` means that you have loaded entity in some transaction, stepped out of it and then tried to use some lazy-loaded property of this entity.

Comment: I think this is all in the same transaction. I do the whole thing in one "block"

Comment: and if it would be not the same transaction, shouldn't it fail every time?

Comment: can you post whole code of the class containing this System.out.println(...) ?

Answer (score 0):

since your whole code is not here, i assume your name query is not always returning the same entity and when the entity returned contains some `Code` it trows error.

your transaction must be closed cause otherwise u will not receive lazy initialyzing problem.

Comment: The namedQuery alwas returns the same entity. (there is only one with my test parameters)

Answer (score 0):

You should check that the creation of `EntityManagerFactory` is executed only once.  For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  EntityManagerFactory emf = EntityManagerFactoryHelper.getFactory(PersistenceUnitsEnum.TEST_STAGE);
  for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    readPolice(emf);
  }
}

private static void readPolice(EntityManagerFactory emf) throws Exception {
  EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
  ...
}
```

If you're using some kind of singleton pattern in `EntityManagerFactoryHelper.getFactory()`, make sure it is thread safe.

You can also try to wrap `readPolice()` inside a transaction by calling `em.getTransaction().begin()` and `em.getTransaction().commit()`.  For example:

```
private static void readPolice(EntityManagerFactory emf) throws Exception {
   EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
   em.getTransaction().begin();
   ...
   em.getTransaction().commit();
   em.close();
}
```

Comment: Your anser brought me a step further (i think). if i execute the creation of the entitymanger just once (per test-call) it works everytime (or it fails everytime) ... so i think it depends on the entityManager, if it works - or not. But what could cause this?